# R: How to boxplot with multiple categories

Tags: r, categories, boxplot

I have a data.frame like that looks like this:

```
date <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-08-14 08:04:50", "2015-08-14 08:06:50", "2015-08-14 08:015:50", "2015-08-15 08:17:50", "2015-08-15 08:23:50")
transport <- c("bus", "bus", "train", "train", "train")
no2 <- c(74, 78, 100, 90, 85)
df <- data.frame(date, transport, no2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

I want to produce a boxplot that it would be according to transport mode and for different days as well. So basically I want it to be by two categories: by day and by transport mode. As far as I know, in boxplot function x and y is defined, so y can be plotted according to x.

Does anybody have an idea how to use two categories?

Another similar question about boxplots: 
I have data like that:

```
date <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-08-14 08:04:50", "2015-08-14 08:06:50", "2015-08-14 08:015:50", "2015-08-15 08:17:50", "2015-08-15 08:23:50"))
no2_site1 <- c(74, 78, 100, 90, 85)
no2_site2 <- c(84, 88, 110, 100, 95)
df <- data.frame(date, no2_site1, no2_site2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My aim is to make a boxplot that it would show NO2 concentrations in both sites (2 boxes for each day) for different days.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates include the time, the time needs to be removed so that you have discrete days. Then, write an R formula (`y ~ x * x2 ...` notation) that describes `no2` values are dependent upon the interaction between `date` and `transport`.

```
df$date = strftime(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
df$date = factor(df$date)
boxplot(no2 ~ date * transport, data = df, col=(c("gold","darkgreen")))
```

Here is the code for `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=no2)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=date))+ facet_grid(~ transport, scales='free_x')
```

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you! :) Now just thinking how to add a bunch of labels for both dates and transport mode since I have a larger data.frame than this small example.

Comment: With ggplot. Do you know how to remove NAs in the plot? Well, it shows a section for NA's.

Comment: Hm, something changed but the section is still there.